# Run two C scripts in synchrony in ubuntu terminal

Tags: c, bash

I have two scripts which I want to run in synchrony. Each one runs in a different terminal and I want them to start only when I press a Keyboard key I choose. But as they are in different terminals I think That won't work. Any suggestions of a better way?

Comment: 1. What are 'C scripts'?, 2. Why not writing one program and fork two process from there when you're specified key was pressed?

Comment: Can you explain what you really want to do ? Why must they be in different terminals ?

Comment: @nouney each program will connect a device by bluetooth, and then I have to send a string to each device. I want the string to be sent at the same time.

Comment: Do they really need to be in separate terminals?

Comment: Ok so the akluth's solution will be fine.
You can write one executable which create 2 processes with `fork` or you can write 3 executables : your 2 "scripts" and another one, which use `fork` and run the scripts.

Comment: The problem is, They both need to connect to the devices and then at teh same time the strings are sent to each other.

Comment: "At the same time" is not a well defined concept.

Comment: ok, :) one after the other.

Comment: The word "script" is generaly used to refer to a program written in an interpreted language, for example a shell script or a Perl script. C programs are usually referred to as programs.

Comment: "*one after the other*" -- So run one, then run the other, but that's pretty much the opposite of what you asked. Please update your question to clarify just what kind of synchronization you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start both of them up and have them wait on a synchronization primitive such as a mutex. Then, reset that mutex from a script/program/whatever using your single keyboard press, to trigger both scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need two separate terminals.

```
mkfifo pipe1
mkfifo pipe2
./script1 <pipe1 &
./script2 <pipe2 &
echo string1 >pipe1; echo string2 >pipe2
```